# How to remove last x chars of an element in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a long list of numbers.

Something like:

```
num_list = ["9222111X 9555222X", "9777666X 9555111X", "9333555X 9444222X"]..
```

I'd like to remove the last x elements of a list to make every element in my list the same length.

I'd like to remove all the numbers after the "X" leaving only 4. Like this:

```
num_list = ["9222X 9555X", "9777X 9555X", "9333X 9444X"]
```

Comment: Check out [ask] and [mcve] for details on how to ask a good question. What have you tried and why didn't it work? What seems to be the problem, in other words.

Comment: Can you please show what you tried so far, so that we can correct you.

Comment: 1. Your expected result doesn't match with your intention of removing numbers after X. 2. You have two different requirements: remove the last x elemtnt and remove all the numbers after X. What now?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
num_list = ["9222111X 9555222X", "9777666X 9555111X", "9333555X 9444222X"]
new_l = [re.sub('\d{3}(?=X)', '', i) for i in num_list]
```

Output:

```
['9222X 9555X', '9777X 9555X', '9333X 9444X']
```